# Not all code paths return a values

Tags: c#

I have written a function to find the the line by searching the text and after it find that particular line, I want to read the next line and return that text. The function is as follows:

```
public static string NextString(string textfind)
{
    List<string> found = new List<string>();
    string linejd;

    using (StreamReader efile = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while ((linejd = efile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            counter++;
            if (linejd.Contains(textfind))
            {
                found.Add(linejd);
                string nextstring = efile.ReadLine();
                return nextstring;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File name has been defined as:

```
const string FILENAME = @"E:\model\Yen and Lee\AQRun01\eratc.inp";
```

However, I keep on getting error:

> AQ.Program.NextString(string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: put `return nextstring;` outside `using(statement){}`.

Comment: What the method should return when it doesn't enter the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if in your function above, your code doesn't enter the loop or the `if (linejd.Contains(textfind))` block? The function returns no value!

I tend to recommend declaring a function's result variable and setting its value within the function and then returning it at the end:

```
static public string nextstring(string textfind)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    List<string> found = new List<string>();
    string linejd;

    /* ********************************************************
    * Find the line with certain string */

    using (StreamReader efile = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
     // using (efile)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while ((linejd = efile.ReadLine()) != null
                && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))    // Quit the loop once we have a result!
        {
            counter++;
            if (linejd.Contains(textfind))
            {
                found.Add(linejd);
                string nextstring = efile.ReadLine();
                result = nextstring;               }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: While this method will work (and does satisfy the 'best practice' of having as few return statements as possible) it can be quite inefficient if the loop executes a large number of iterations after the answer has already been found.

Comment: Got two errors using your method: `"Error 2 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'` and `Error 1 Non-invocable member 'string.Empty' cannot be used like a method. `

Comment: That'll teach me to not check with a compiler ;) Fixed Empty property and casing of IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: Thank you so much didn't realize that was a error using lower case.

Comment: Also, it's recommended to follow .NET coding convention and use PascalCasing for your function names! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the condition `linejd.Contains(textfind)` is never true then the function will never return anything, yet the function declaration states that it will return a string. You can fix this by returning a default value (such as an empty string) after the using block.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons to why the function could exit without a return value:

1. The file is empty, so the `while` loop is never entered.
2. The condition `linejd.Contains(textfind)` is never `true`.

Even if you know that the file is never empty, and that the string can always be found in the file, the compiler doesn't know that. (Although, the `while` loop doesn't make sense if you know that the string can always be found, as that means that you will never reach the end of the file.)

You need to tell the compiler what to do for both those cases, for example by adding `return null;` at the end of the function.

Alternatively rewrite the code so that it actually relies on the file always containing something and that the string is always found. That way there is no loose ends to take care about. That of course means that the code will crash or hang if the file actually would be empty or the string is not found.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Linq?

```
public static string NextString(string textfind)
{
    return File.ReadLines(FILENAME)
           .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(textfind))
           .Skip(1)
           .First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the if case is always fault, then your method will return nothing.. That's why you get an error.
try writing a return value before the end of your method like:

```
public static string NextString(string textfind)
 {
 List<string> found = new List<string>();
 string linejd;
 string new_string = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader efile = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
{
    int counter = 0;
    while ((linejd = efile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        counter++;
        if (linejd.Contains(textfind))
        {
            found.Add(linejd);
            string nextstring = efile.ReadLine();
            return nextstring;
        }
    }
}


return (new_string);
```

}